# Fatal error: Out of memory (allocated 377487360) (tried to allocate 371200000 bytes)

Tags: php, xampp

I want to scrape data from an URL that contain other URLs contains details of each item using simple_html_dom.php

```
<?php
include 'simple_html_dom.php';
// Create DOM from URL or file
$url='www.example.com';
$count=0;
$Links_Array = array();
$ArrayOfDomHtml=array();

// Find all links in the first page
if(!empty($url))
{
    $html = file_get_html($url);
    foreach($html->find('.li_subject .item_link') as $element) 
    {
             $Links_Array[$count]=$element->href;
             $count++;    
    }
}


// Get  details information from every item

//  Create DOM from URLS


if(!empty($Links_Array))
{
    $count=0;
    foreach($Links_Array as $element) 
            {
                 $ArrayOfDomHtml[$count] = file_get_html($element);
                 $count++;    
            }
}

// Get the title

if(!empty($ArrayOfDomHtml))
{
    $count=0;
    foreach ($ArrayOfDomHtml as  $value) 
    {

          $array2[$count] = array('title' => $value->find('.item_subject') );
          $count++;
    }
}
foreach ($array2 as $value) {
    print_r( $value);
}
?>
```

I am using xampp server
I want to print the value of $array2
I have a problem of memory I have looked for the problem I found several answers like setting in php.ini file

- set memory_limit=-1
- uncoment realpath_cache_size = 4096k
- uncoment realpath_cache_ttl = 120

i have made all this operations but it still doesn't work

[image: Error]

the line 49 is print_r( $value);

### Edit

i have edited the code like this to minimise memory but still doesn't work

```
<?php
include 'simple_html_dom.php';
// Create DOM from URL or file

// Find all links in the first page
if(!empty($url))
{
    $html = file_get_html($url);
    foreach($html->find('.li_subject .item_link') as $element) 
    {
             $Links_Array[$count]=$element->href;
             $count++;    
    }
}


// Get  details information from every item

//  Create DOM from URLS

if(!empty($Links_Array)) {
    $count=0;
    foreach($Links_Array as $url) {
          $html = file_get_html($url);
          $DetailItem[$count] = array('title' => $html ->find('.item_subject') );
          $count++;
    }
}
print_r($DetailItem);
?>
```

Comment: Which is line 49?

Comment: this line print_r( $value);

Comment: have you tried restarting your server? And are you sure you are modifying the correct php.ini?

Comment: yes i am sure i have edited correctly php.ini by setting  memory_limit=-1 and restarting the server

Answer (score 1):

What you *should* be doing *first* is trying to make your program use *less* memory.

Instead of scraping all of the HTML on the planet into memory, and *then* parsing out the one specific bit of info you want, combine those and only store the bit you actually want.

```
if(!empty($Links_Array)) {
    $count=0;
    foreach($Links_Array as $element) {
          $html = file_get_html($element);
          $array2[$count] = array('title' => $value->find('.item_subject') );
          $count++;
    }
}
```

Comment: I have edited the code but still doesn't work problem of memory i have the same error

Answer (score -2):

What I'd do is find the php.ini file, the find the line where it says memory_limit and set it to 2048M just in case to figure out if it's because of memory.

Then you should save this change and restart the server (depending which server you're using apache or nginx).